# Position and z-index of two images as background

Tags: css

I have a two images set as background image

```
background-image: url("one.png"), url("two.svg") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: center center, center bottom;
    -webkit-background-size: cover, auto;
    -moz-background-size: cover, auto;
    -o-background-size: cover, auto;
    background-size: cover, auto;
```

The one.png is at above the two.svg , however i would like to set position of two.svg to overleap with one.png e.g

```
background-position: center center, center bottom top -50px;
```

the statement throws invalid property error.

How can i set the position of images using properties ( top center etc ) as in example , and then adjust the position the image using top left and so on?

Also , it is possible to set something like z-index on this background images?
I would like the two.svg to be "in front of" the one.png .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand what you want to do but i would put them in 2 diffrent divs and then use `z-index` and like this you can put the div with the png in `position: relative;` and the div with the svg in `position: absolute;` and then do the `top: -50px; bottom: -50px;` and `left: calc( 50% - half of the div of the svg)`
I hope it helps you